# Entity framework one-to-many relationship with unique entities

Tags: entity-framework, relational-database, primary-key, entity-relationship, unique-key

I have Product and Customer entities. One Customer can be related to multiple Products, one Product can be related to only one Customer. Customer cannot exist without Product, thus Customers are only created when a new Product is added. This sounds as an easy scenario, but the thing is that I want only unique Customers in my table. I mean, if new Product is added to the database and he is assigned a Customer that already exists in the database (determined by Primary Key), then the new Product is assigned a relation to the existing Customer, instead of the duplicate Customer being added to the database. Is there a clean way to achieve this naturally by using Entity Framework relations or should I plug in some external logic of my own to control Customer creation and assignment to Products? In both ways, please show me some example or describe the scenario in short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entities should be setup something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then whenever you save a Product you have to check whether the customer exists in the DB and assign that customer. If the customer on the product has a valid PK then it will update the database if not it will create a customer. EF will take care of this on save. For example:

```
var customer = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = id);
var product = new Product()
{
    Customer = customer ?? new Customer()
};
```

Comment: I've found a solution myself before you answered. It's the same, but yours is many times more elegant, because you only take one line of code to determine whether a new Customer should be created and leave everything else for the framework. I'm definitely accepting your answer. You nailed it! Big thanks for support and such clear and comprehensive example!

Comment: Customer = customer ?? new Customer(); would be enough